# A parsing question from the book, R for Data Science. parse_time?

Tags: r, parsing, time

I've beat this parse() problem to death and can't seem to find the solution.  This question comes from the book, R for Data Science, Chapter 8, Data import with readr, problem 7, pg 137.

Using one of the parse_date(), parse_time(), parse_datetime() functions, generate the correct format string to parse:

```
library(readr)

t2 <- "11:15:10.12 PM"
```

I've tried the obvious and tried many variations without success. It would be nice to see how this is done.

The following codes, and various renditions of these codes have been tried without success. I ultimately keep circling back to the following code,

```
parse_time(t2, "%H%M%OS" ), or (t2, "%I%M%OS")
```

The error that is returned follows,

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:16: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
1: parse_time(t2, "%I%M%OS)
                   ^
Traceback:
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you need to use is `"%I:%M:%OS %p"`

```
readr::parse_time(t2, "%I:%M:%OS %p")
#23:15:10.12
```

Without milli-second information

```
readr::parse_time(t2, "%I:%M:%S %p")
#23:15:10
```

`as.POSIXct` in base R also follows the same format but it adds todays date to the time

```
as.POSIXct(t2, format = "%I:%M:%OS %p", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2019-12-02 23:15:10 UTC"
```